# Android client only connecting once to server with LipeRMI

Tags: java, android, rmi

I have an Android client connecting to a Java server with LipeRMI (http://lipermi.sourceforge.net/).

To test this communication I have a button in my interface that when clicked sends a String "Test". It gets to the server and the server returns the String. It works fine, the problem is that it only works once. The server only accepts one time.

My Server code is the following:

```
public class TestServer implements TestService {

public TestServer() {
    try {
        CallHandler callHandler = new CallHandler();
        callHandler.registerGlobal(TestService.class, this);
        Server server = new Server();
        server.bind(7777, callHandler);
        server.addServerListener(new IServerListener() {

            @Override
            public void clientDisconnected(Socket socket) {
                System.out.println("Client Disconnected: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            }

            @Override
            public void clientConnected(Socket socket) {
                System.out.println("Client Connected: " + socket.getInetAddress());
            }
        });
        System.out.println("Server Listening");
    } catch (LipeRMIException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public String getResponse(String data) {
    System.out.println("getResponse called");
    System.out.println("The information received was: " + data);

    return "Your data: " + data;
}
```

And in the Android client, in my MainActivity I have the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String serverIP = "192.168.3.8";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button btnGet = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);
    btnGet.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            new Conn().execute();
        }
    });

}

class Conn extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, MainActivity> {

    @Override
    protected MainActivity doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Looper.prepare();
        try {
            CallHandler callHandler = new CallHandler();
            Client client = new Client(serverIP, 7777, callHandler);
            TestService testService = (TestService) client.getGlobal(TestService.class);

            String msg = testService.getResponse("Test");
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            client.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Looper.loop();
        return null;
    }
}
```

They have the TestService interface in common so that I can use the methods from the server.

How can I change the server so that it can accept any number of times a call from the Android Client?

Comment: Are you counting connections or invocations?

Comment: No, I'm not in any way.

Comment: Yes you are, because you said the server only accepts one time. You can't know that without counting. My question is what are you counting as an accept: a connection or an invocation?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I deleted the `Looper.prepare()` and `Looper.loop()` calls in the `doInBackground` method from AsyncTask. It solved the problem in my case.